# TED scraping with python and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm discovering some issues while scraping [www.ted.com](http://www.ted.com) website in order to get the lenght of the videos, I read the links to the video from a csv and create a URL to access the video pages and their information

```
import bs4
import requests
import csv
pre_link = "https://www.ted.com/talks/"
path_csv = ["../dataset/tedx_dataset.csv",
            "../dataset/tags_dataset.csv", "../dataset/watch_next_dataset.csv"]
v_duration=[]
#Cleans the strings in order to get a correct URL
def cleanString(s):
    no_char = '.:/&?¿()+—=!\"|,â€”'
    r=s.replace(" ","__")
    r=''.join(x for x in ritorno if x not in no_char)
    r = r.replace("\'", "_")
    r= r.replace("ñ", "n")
    r= r.replace("à", "a")
    r= r.replace("è", "e")
    r= r.replace("é", "e")
    r= r.replace("ì", "i")
    r= r.replace("ö", "o")
    r= r.replace("-", "_")
    r= r.replace("__", "_")
    return r

# Export from csv
with open(path_csv[0], newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as file_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(file_csv, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        speaker = str(row[1]).lower()
        title = str(row[2]).lower()
        # Cleaning the dirty data in order to get a correct URL
        link = pre_link+cleanString(speaker)+"_"+cleanString(title)
        link=link.replace("__","_")
        response=requests.get(link)
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        temp=soup.find_all("div", class_="")
        print(temp)
        break
```

The code above seems to stop at the first div of the HTML structure which is with an id="__next" while I'm trying to get to a deeper level inside of this div, any ideas?